# Windows server 2019 standard desktop suddenly vanished

Tags: windows, graphical-user-interface

My server has Windows Server 2019 Standard (with Desktop Environment) but the GUI Shell disappeared suddenly after a server reboot.

All the GUI Features like browser, windows explorer is working. Just no desktop, no start menu

Looks like this now:

[image: strange behavious]

If I try to do `Install-WindowsFeature server-gui-mgmt-infra, server-gui-shell Install-WindowsFeature : ArgumentNotValid` It acts like what a Server 2019 Core would do

Please help

Comment: Open a new instance of explorer.exe to re-initialize the desktop.

Comment: @Overmind It just opens the file explorer just like what I showed in the picture. Also rebooting does not help

Comment: Do you get the same result if from task manager you select 'explorer' and 'restart' ?

Comment: @Overmind yes unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The run exeplorer.exe method worked until recently.

With the May 2019 Update Windows Explorer process changes as follows:

Starting with the Windows 10 May 2019 Update, the Start menu will appear as a separate StartMenuExperienceHost.exe process to streamline debugging and isolate the feature from possible problems.

However, you won't necessarily need to terminate both processes to troubleshoot issues, as ending the Explorer.exe will also automatically reset the new Start process. Just keep in mind that if you end the StartMenuExperienceHost.exe process it won't terminate the Explorer.exe process. Also, unlike Explorer.exe, whether you terminate or restart the process, StartMenuExperienceHost.exe should always start again automatically.

In the rare case that the Start menu doesn't start automatically (no pun intended), then you can force it to do so.

Instead of just end-tasking explorer.exe and re-running it, use the following command after re-initializing explorer:

```
%SystemRoot%\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe
```

Basically, a new .exe re-launches the UI instead of explorer.exe.